# Order of ON and JOIN in query execution

Tags: sql-server, select, logical-operators

Refering to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) regarding the order of execution of SELECT query, there is an `ON` mentioned before `JOIN`.

```
FROM
ON
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

I tend to think this `ON` is the `ON` clause as part of the `JOIN`.

- If it is false, what is this `ON` ?
- If it is true, then it is a bit confusing, because I think when doing a `JOIN`, SQL Server do a `CROSS JOIN` before filtering with `ON`. This may not be strictly correct as SQL server has some mechanism to optimize this process, something regarding chosing one smaller table as inner table to loop the outer table as I remember correctly for the `ON` condition. Then in this case, wouldn't `JOIN` be before `ON` in execution order ?

Could you shed some light on what I mention ?

Comment: See http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf

Comment: Yes that confirms what I said about JOIN before ON, opposite to Microsoft website. And there may be a big error : your link says TOP before ORDER BY ! I am surprised because Itzik Ben-Gan wrote this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes . The ON is for the Join
2. This is the Logical order . The physical order might be different . Your link also mentions this .

Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is

### determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.

Comment: I am always talking about logical order. The discrepancy is that _JOIN executed before ON_ as we agreed but Micsoft say otherwise.

Comment: If you know on which column you're about to filter , then you might chose different index  . Hence why on is first